# asp.net mvc 3 with .net 4 and runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I had my mvc site with

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true
```

and had no problem, then I found, that for .net 4 I can disable it and have faster processing of static resources, I've changed to false and bam - 404 on my controller actions. I'm running my mvc application on IIS 7.5 with integrated app pool, have windows 7 with sp1. Am I missing something?

Comment: why dont you provide source of that claim that you can disable it ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx. Thing is, that I have IIS 7.5 instead of IIS 7 mentioned and as long as I can't install mentioned kb, I'm assuming, that it is not needed anymore. So may be someone made it work on IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, after banging head to wall, I've found the issue - wrong route map record. Moral is - don't change two things at the time if don't like banging wall with your head.